# Внутренняя ссылка

Tags: html, ссылка

подскажите как создать внутреннюю ссылку на сайте, но так чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, переход осуществлялся так, чтобы необходимый якорь оказывался примерно по центру страницы, а не вверху, так как у меня есть вверху закрепленное меню, которое перекрывает текст, на который указывает якорь

Comment: клик по якорю переместит за якоренный блок в саммый верх ...изменить это поведение можно на javascript

Comment: можете подсказать как? просто я больше связан с пхп, а мой коллега просто сильно занят. Мне это нужно как шаблон хотя бы

Comment: напишите в любом поисковике такой запрос "плавный скролл к якорю " и там будут примеры в которых обязательным параметром будет pageY или pageYoffset

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте этот якорь отдельным, внутри нужного блока, и спозиционируйте его выше чем нужный блок:

```
<div class="content-block">
    <div class="goto-anchor" id="some-id"></div>
    Контент блока, к которому нужно проскролить страницу.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.goto-anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
}
```

Поправьте top на размер верхнего меню, плюс немного отступа. А размещать в середине не советую - много нюансов и вычислений потребуется.
Ссылка:

```
<a href="#some-id">Ссылка на блок</a>
```

Comment: вы имеете ввиду просто css код добавить к якорю

Comment: css для дива якоря нужен только чтобы его сделать выше родительского блока на величину меню. тогда браузер будет к этому диву скролить, который выше нужного блока.

Comment: то есть этот див - не ваш изначальный блок, а новый внутри прежнего

Comment: то есть код такого вида должен работать? `<div class="goto-anchor"><a name="akk"></a></div>some text.<a href="#akk">some text</a>`

Comment: нет. внутри дива ничего не нужно. К нему просто браузер скролит, в нём нет содержимого, это просто элемент. А ссылка где-то в другом месте, просто ссылается на этот див, потому что имеет такой же id в адресе.

Comment: допустим я убрал `<a name="akk"></a>`, но все равно ничего не изменилось, я изменил id, как надо, меню все равно перекрывает, хотя я пробовал разное количество px

Comment: Отредактировал для понятности. Убедитесь, что страницу заново открываете, иначе браузер кэширует позиции блоков и будет неверно скролить.

Comment: это все я проверяю, страница у меня не кэшируется

Comment: Можете показать пример на каком-то хостинге, где это не работает? Потому что у меня работает на моем проекте. Только вчера аналогичное делал (ещё на боевой не залил). Браузер видит блок выше чем родительсий и скролит к нему.